# What's the best (simplest) free software to beat-match and mix two tracks?

Tags: windows, osx, music

I want to mix a few tracks (in .mp3 format for example) together to create a seamless bit of dance music for a performance. I'd like to pick a particular section in two songs and the software should then combine the result to fade one out and fade the other in.

What are my options for Mac or Windows?

Comment: Do you care about pricing?

Comment: I guess you want live beatmatching? Or is a software that just generates a .mp3 file OK?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Mixx](http://www.mixxx.org/download/):

- free and open-source
- Linux/Windows/Mac
- synchronization and auto-beatmatching (+ usual features of a DJ software)

See [all features](http://www.mixxx.org/features/).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Virtual Dj Free Home Version.

It will work on Windows and Mac.

You can find the software on virtual dj webpage, [here](http://www.virtualdj.com/products/homefree.html.)